# premature loop exits in store procedure function works correctly but not runs for all variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a single table with duplicate id.i created a table with distinct id and count of that id i want to compare and update based on that id

```
+----+-------+ 
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 1:a   |
|  1 | 1     |
|  1 | 2:b   |
+----+-------+
```

expected output

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 1:a 1 |
|  1 | 2:b   |
+----+-------+
```

what i have tried is i have written a procedure which executes perfectly but it prematurely exist the loop. i don't know why it exits can anyone guide me

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE value_merge()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_val INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE row_cou INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE colan INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE mm_num varchar(20) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE merge_value varchar(132000) DEFAULT "";

 DEClARE merge_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT Material_Number,cou FROM zz_plant_data_given_table_form_work_bhai where flag='y';
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_val = 1;
 OPEN merge_cursor;
 get_loop: LOOP
 FETCH merge_cursor INTO mm_num,row_cou;
 IF v_val = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_loop;
 END IF;
  while i<=row_cou do
    SELECT Basic_Data_Text INTO merge_value FROM `zz_plant_data_given_table_form_work` where Material_Number=mm_num and seq=row_cou;
    set colan=ROUND ((LENGTH(merge_value)- LENGTH( REPLACE (merge_value, ":", "") )) / LENGTH(":"));
    IF colan>0 THEN
    set row_cou=row_cou-1;
    ELSE
    update `zz_plant_data_given_table_form_work` set sts='y' where Material_Number=mm_num and seq=row_cou;
    set row_cou=row_cou-1;
    update zz_plant_data_given_table_form_work set Basic_Data_Text=concat(Basic_Data_Text,' ',merge_value) where Material_Number=mm_num and seq=row_cou;
    END IF;
END while;
update zz_plant_data_given_table_form_work_bhai set flag='' where Material_Number=mm_num;
 END LOOP get_loop;
 CLOSE merge_cursor;
END//
DELIMITER
```

;

Comment: I think there might be no need for a stored procedure at all. Please instead of your approach show us what you want to get done with sample data, table structure and expected output (edit your question).

Answer (score 0):

This two sentences fires the `NOT FOUND`  handler, so I suggest use another type of query to get `merge_value`

[image]

Change it for:

```
set merge_value =   ( SELECT Basic_Data_Text  
                       FROM `zz_plant_data_given_table_form_work` 
                       where Material_Number=mm_num 
                        and seq=row_cou
                       limit 1 ); /* to prevent errors*/
```